# Perform Page optimization in SP 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, publishing-page

I want to optimize the page load time from 25 seconds to  5 seconds in my SP 2013 portal.
Any methodology / technic /approaches for achieving this

Comment: What do you have in your page currently that is taking so much time?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Am having more than 10 web parts which pull data from different site collections.so its taking more than 20 seconds to load the page for the end user. Customer  is asking can you reduce it to 5 seconds.What's the alternative for this performance issue.

Comment: What web parts are you using?

Comment: Visual Web parts using VS 2012.Does that affects the performance of portal?

Answer (score 1):

Enable output cache, enable blobcache. Alternatively consider dividing the 10 web parts to separate pages and create a nice navigation for the user to switch between the web part pages.